# Display a existing CanvasBitmap directly

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to display an existing `Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasBitmap` in my application **without saving and loading** a file because it is slow and makes problems when accessed by two threads. I have found two potential ways to display them.

1. Convert the `CanvasBitmap` to a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` and display it with the`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image` control by setting the `Image.Source` to the `BitmapImage`. However the only way if found to convert it is by creating a stream to a file and writing into it with `CanvasBitmap.SaveAsync(fileStream)` so it's not direct.
2. Draw the `CanvasBitmap` in a `Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasControl`. However I need to preload the `CanvasBitmap` and the only way I found was by using `CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync()` (static) where you have to set a path or filestream to the Image. I would need to load the existing CanvasBitmap.

I would be very happy about a solution or another way.

Comment: Use a MemoryStream in stead of a filestream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you need to  use `CanvasRenderTarget` to create DrawingSession and draw your image. then convert it to `SoftwareBitmap` For more please refer to the following code.

```
var device = new CanvasDevice();
var renderer = new CanvasRenderTarget(device,
                                      cabitmap.SizeInPixels.Width,
                                      cabitmap.SizeInPixels.Height, cabitmap.Dpi);
using (var ds = renderer.CreateDrawingSession())
{     
    ds.DrawImage(cabitmap,0,0);
}

InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await renderer.SaveAsync(randomAccessStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png);
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);
var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
    softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Straight)
{
    softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
}

var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
await source.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);

// Set the source of the Image control
imageControl.Source = source;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Also i could directly use .SaveAsync on the CanvasBitmap.